# Selecting and operating on columns in a .csv

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv with 38 columns and 1500+ rows which contains floats and strings. I want 3 columns (x,y,z) of float data from this set to find the average of `f=(x+y)/z`. After research I successfully isolated these columns as numpy arrays and performed `f=(x+y)/z`. Now when I try to sum f the array isn't added up. I print f And I see 1500 items of correct values but not the sum of these.

```
  reader=csv.reader(open('myfile.csv' ,"rb"),delimiter=',')
  reader.next()
  reader.next()
  x=list(reader)
  data=numpy.array(x)
  rows=data.shape[0]
  for i in range (0,rows):
      x=numpy.array(data[i,18]).astype('float')
      y=numpy.array(data[i,19]).astype('float')
      z=numpy.array(data[i,6]).astype('float')
      f=numpy.array((x+y)/z)
      average=numpy.sum(f)/rows
      print average
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `data` is already an array, you don't need the `for` loop:

```
x = data[:, 18].astype(float)
y = data[:, 19].astype(float)
z = data[:, 6].astype(float)
f = (x+y) / z
average = np.average(f)
```

You would probably be better off by reading your file with [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
data = np.loadtxt('myfile.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',' skiprows=2,
                  usecols=(6, 18, 19))
```

or to get `x`, `y` and `z` directly:

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt('myfile.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',' skiprows=2,
                     usecols=(6, 18, 19), unpack=True)
```

Comment: I was writing up the equivalent of your first solution except I used `x,y,z = data[:, [18, 19, 6]].astype(float).T` and `f.mean()`, which amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy allows you to operate on the arrays as a whole, you don't need to iterate through them.

```
reader=csv.reader(open('myfile.csv' ,"rb"),delimiter=',')
reader.next()
reader.next()
x=list(reader)
data=numpy.array(x)
rows=data.shape[0]

x=data[:,18].astype('float')
y=data[:,19].astype('float')
z=data[:,6].astype('float')

f = (x + y) / z
average = f.mean()

print average
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not locked into numpy here is a pure python solution,

```
import csv

def f(x, y, z):
    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    z = float(z)
    return (x+y)/z

reader = csv.reader(open("derp.csv", 'r'))
rows = list(reader)
len_of_rows = len(rows)

f_values = []

for row in rows:
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]
    z = row[2]
    f_values.append(f(x, y, z))

average = sum(f_values)/len_of_rows
print average
```

Here is what my derp.csv looks like

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```